# Converting AJAX request to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

Hi I am completely new to jQuery and also not the strongest with Javascript so I would appreciate some input on modifying this AJAX request to jQuery.

```
var test = new Array();

var bindThis = {
    url: "sampleHandler.data",
    method: "post",
    }
    mimetype: "text/json",
    content:  test
};
var request1 = dojo.io.bind(bindThis);
dojo.event.connect(request1, "load", this, "ResultsFunction");
```

My guest is this but I am not 100% sure I have the syntax correct.

```
var test = new Array();

var bindThis = {
    url: "sampleHandler.data",
    type: "post",
    }
    dataType: "text/json",
    data:  test
};
```

As for the dojo event handler I haven't been able to find a great resource on how to bind the request. My guest is something along these
 lines?

```
$(this).load(function(){"ResultsFunction"})
```

How am I making out? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I forgot to add that this is an application that uses both Dojo and Prototype. I am trying to migrate the code to jQuery.

Comment: if you are just starting out... mixing 2 libraries is going to be more than confusing. Run your code through jslint.com to validate syntax. There are several syntax problems

Comment: I think he is trying to port existing Dojo code to jQuery (or starting a new jQuery project, having only Dojo knowledge), not using both in the same project

Comment: A piece of JS advice unrelated to Ajax: use `[]` rather than `new Array()`. `var test = [];` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

From the [jQuery AJAX API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
    $.ajax({
        type:       'POST',
        url:        'sampleHandler.data',
        data:       data,
        dataType:   'json',
        success:    function (result)
        {

        }
    });
```

Alternatively

```
    $.post("sampleHandler.data", data,
        function(result) {
    }, 
        "json"
    );
```

[More info](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: The API docs are your friend, they give you both an overview of the function and several examples of usage.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to perform a POST operation, most likely you want to send data that needs to be serialized to a JSON format (if your server operation is expecting that type of data), here's an example:

```
var dataToSend = {'taco':'yum'};
$.ajax({
        url:'/myurl/',
        dataType:'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),                
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            // perform operation with the data you receive
           alert('success! received: ' + data);
        }
});
```

You can get more info if you visit: [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com)